# What happen to organic solar cell when applied electric field?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering, solar-cells

For example, I have a PTB7:PCBM organic solar cell. I applied electric field in forward basis. Will it contribute to increase charge separation?  Then, if I do in  reverse basis, what will happen to the solar cell?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Organic solar cells are excitonic solar cells. The applied electric potential can therefore have strong effect on the first step of the entire photovoltaic functioning of the device. While in a bilayer exciton dissociate due to the donor acceptor character of the coupled materials, in a bulk heterojunction this driving force might be less effective, e.g. due to an overly homogeneous structure. Can you perform EQE meas? I HOPE to find the time for an answer.  The info I request should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IV-curves will be similar to those of any pn-junction:
[image]